# Restrict access to AWS ELB from gateway API only

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I want AWS gateway API to be entry point of application cluster. I have 20+ machines running in my VPC which are required for various purposes (RMQ, Worker, etc). I was expecting gateway api to offload the SSL, authenticate request with AWS signature and then forward it to my ELB. And then, some way to secure my internet facing ELB to accept requests just from API gateway. Turns out it's not possible. I have to run SSL on my deployed NGINX server and use AWS client certificate authentication to validate the origin of request. This still keeps my end points exposed to DDos and there is overhead of SSL as well.

Now, with newly launched network load balancer and VPC link at gateway api level is is possible to achieve above?

Comment: Yes, that's specifically the purpose of that new feature.  It's unclear what you're looking for in an answer.